# Combobox won't load database values

Tags: c#, mvvm, combobox, entity-framework-6

The comboBoxes in my app seem sensitive for reasons best known to them.

I'm using the MVVM pattern on a signup page. This means that the information in my view are all loaded from a class (ViewModel) I made and the only code behind the UserControls(Views) have is the setting of the DataContext.

I'm using the entity framework 6 so the user control textboxes and coboboxes are bound to the collection view class.

So there's a data context set to the CollectionView class set in the xaml:

```
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource signupsViewSource}">
```

One in the userControl's code behind like this:

```
DataContext = new registrationSQL();
```

And this is the part that vexes me. The ViewModel:

You see when I place the code like this the comboboxes load perfectly:

```
    class registrationSQL
{
    #region Declarations
    // Medcare2 is the name of the app
    Medcare2.mascamainDataSet mascamainDataSet = ((Medcare2.mascamainDataSet)(Application.Current.FindResource("mascamainDataSet")));
    Medcare2.mascamainDataSetTableAdapters.signupsTableAdapter mascamainDataSetsignupTableAdapter = new Medcare2.mascamainDataSetTableAdapters.signupsTableAdapter();
    System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource signupsViewSource = (System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)Application.Current.Resources["signupsViewSource"];
    mascamainEntities context = new mascamainEntities();

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public registrationSQL()
    {
        // Fill the dataset table signups
        mascamainDataSetsignupTableAdapter.Fill(mascamainDataSet.signups);
        // Select the first record
        signupsViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
    }

    #endregion
```

When that's done the entire user control loads fine:

[image: When comboboxes are working]

Which is okay. However when I tell the Window to open another UserControl, which is supposed to load the same information (Just with a different layout), using the same ViewModel and collectionView, The CollectionView switches back it's selection to the first record. When what I need it to do is to stay on the already selected record.

[image: The problem with loading the data this way]

So this happens because when the next UserControl is opened, it initialises a new instance of the ViewModel and the command to move the selection to the first record is done all over again. To avoid this I decided to implement a static instance of the Viewmodel.

```
private static registrationSQL instance = new registrationSQL();
    public static registrationSQL Instance
    {
        get
        { return instance; }
    }
```

and set the data context to it on both UserControls.

```
DataContext = registrationSQL.Instance;
```

However when I run the app, The first user control loads fine, the second UC takes off from the record the first left off on, but the comboboxes aren't loading, even if I scroll to the next or previous record.

[image: Combobox not loading]

Any clues as what to do in order to get them to convey the data?

*Edit*

I may need to add that in order for me to get the comboBoxes to work, I need to scroll to the very begining / end until there is no record loaded in the veiw then scroll back onto the first / last record again.

Alternatively I can load them like this but when done this way, I'm not sure if there's any way to add customised comboBox Items to the drop down options:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="genderComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
        </ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

for the 1st issue: to stay on the same record

=> when u click on the form tab, at that particular time, check whether "tag" text area is null or not, if not null, then send that "tag" number to the data fetching database code to get that info.

u r getting this issue becoz, the tab childrens are different, u need to override the text it contains again with the values is deserves.

may be for 2nd:
 u may need to reload the checkbox to initialize again.
(still for the 2nd issue: please elaborate)

Comment: Well I did consider doing that. But if I can't think of any way of doing that without breaking the MVVM pattern. If I'm going to do it without breaking the pattern, I'd have to use the property Tag is bound to yet the properties in question are not in the ViewModel I described above. They're in the collectionViewSource. And I'm not too sure how to access the Tag property the Tag textbox is databound to.

Comment: @Offer r u saving the form data to any database or so? apart from collectionviewsource..

`Text="{Binding /*ur property to get the tag content*/, Mode=TwoWay}"
private string _tagno;
        public string tagno
        {
            get
            {
                return _tagno;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_tagno == value)
                    return;
                _tagno = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(() => SecurityDescription);

            }
        }
`
u can u get the tag text..